# Design adaptive layout for login screen using autolayout

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

Good day everyone i am new to ios development . currently i am learning auto layout . i am trying to design a login screen but my design does not look perfect on different screen sizes. i want to adjust the vertical spacing between uielements according to screen size . can anyone help how can i do that ? thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scrollview.

**Or**

Set "Welcome User" as **top constraint** and "New user? Click hear" as **bottom constraint**.
and other set **vertical spacing** constraint and set **relation greater then equal to**.

Comment: i have set greater than eqal to relation to vertical space of views . but it is showing inequality constraint ambiguity error

Comment: you can not set all constraint greater than equal to relation to vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

Super simple way is to embed all uielement in vertical **stack view**. 
And set **spacing** or **distribution** according to your requirement, Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set:

- Horizontally in the container alignment constraints to position all your items in the center.
- Vertically in the container to set their vertical position(enter different values in the multiplier to see what suits you)
- Each item equal width to your view and again enter the desired value in the multiplier